# A kind of actions handler on my PHP project?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to do something like actions handler. I don't know how it should look like. But I started to make something like that:

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `handlers` (
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`key` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`handler` varchar(65) NOT NULL default ''
) TYPE=MyISAM ;
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']){
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM handlers WHERE key = '.$action.'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    // and here is the problem...
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how should I execute string as an function in PHP?

For example if string in `handler` is `Test`, then code should execute function `Test();`. I was thinking about `eval();` but I don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: I just wanted to note that your example code is extremely dangerous. You should *never* insert user input directly into a query like that. Consider using PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: @leo why should PDO be better than mysqli in this case?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider PDO would allow $action to be passed in as a parameter instead of directly concatenating user input into the query (a practice that will cause your application to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks).

Comment: @leo so does mysqli. You should advise to switch to prepared statements instead of advising to use a different library (that does the same) without telling the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd do something like this in a real project, but you can make it work the way you describe like so:

```
$handler = $row['handler'];
if (function_exists ($handler)) {
  $handler ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call following

```
$functionName = $row['handler'];
$functionName();
```

alternative is

```
call_user_func($functionName);
```